# how to remove attribute of a etree Element?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I've Element of etree having some attributes - how can we delete the attribute of perticular etree Element.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`.attrib` member of the element object](http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#attributes) contains the dict of attributes - you can use `.pop("key")` or `del` [like you would on any other dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to remove a key-val pair.

Comment: I found 1 another solution etree.strip_attrbutes(element,'attribute_name'))

Comment: While `pop` works, `del` does not: `AttributeError: attribute 'attrib' of 'lxml.etree._Element' objects is not writable` - 
see also the [Element](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) documentation which speaks of a dict like interface, but also does not mention `pop`.

Comment: @shahjapan etree.strip_attrbutes is not safe because it will Delete all attributes with the provided attribute names from an Element (or ElementTree) and its descendants. http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_attributes

Comment: The documentation says `Note that while the attrib value is always a real mutable Python dictionary, an ElementTree implementation may choose to use another internal representation, and create the dictionary only if someone asks for it. To take advantage of such implementations, use the dictionary methods below whenever possible.` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree). Isn't this solution breaking that recommendation?

Answer (score 14):

You do not need to `try/except` while you are popping a key which is unavailable.  Here is how you can do this.

### Code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()      

print(root.attrib)  # {'xyz': '123'}

root.attrib.pop("xyz", None)  # None is to not raise an exception if xyz does not exist

print(root.attrib)  # {}

ET.tostring(root)
'<urlset> <url> <changefreq>daily</changefreq> <loc>http://www.example.com</loc></url></urlset>'
```

Answer (score 10):

**Example :**

```
>>> from lxml import etree 
>>> from lxml.builder import E
>>> otree = E.div()
>>> otree.set("id","123")
>>> otree.set("data","321")
>>> etree.tostring(otree)
'<div id="123" data="321"/>'
>>> del otree.attrib["data"]
>>> etree.tostring(otree)
'<div id="123"/>'
```

Take care sometimes you dont have the attribute:

It is always suggested that we handle exceptions.

```
try:
    del myElement.attrib["myAttr"]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: It is somewhat better to only catch the expected exceptions in case something else went wrong. In this case:

except KeyError: